# How to make 3-D sphere cluster?

Tags: python, arrays

#I want to generate 3-D sphere cluster which contains number of points in it.
I am using this code but I am unable to generate.#

```
import math
N = 50
thetavec = np.linspace(0,pi,N)
phivec = np.linspace(0,2*pi,2*N)
[th, ph] = np.meshgrid(thetavec,phivec)
R = np.ones(th.shape)

x = R*numpy.sin(th)*numpy.cos(ph)
y = R*numpy.sin(th)*numpy.sin(ph)
z = R*numpy.cos(th)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('sphere')
```

I have generated these spherical clusters from matlab but now I want to generate from python:

[image]

After that code I am getting points on the sphere but I want the points to be inside the sphere as shown in 1st image means the number of points building a cluster in spherical shape

[image: image 2]
Help me out

Comment: _"unable to generate"_ what goes wrong?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) You're trying `math.sin` and `math.cos` on `th` and `ph` which are `numpy` `array`s. Use `numpy.sin` and `numpy.cos`

Comment: thanks for the help, I am using this code but I am getting number of points over the sphere not inside it. Can you tell where I am doing wrong this time?

Comment: `import math
`import numpy as np`

`N = 50`
`thetavec = np.linspace(0,math.pi,N)`
`phivec = np.linspace(0,2*math.pi,2*N)`
`[th, ph] = np.meshgrid(thetavec,phivec)`
`R = np.ones(th.shape)`

`x = R*np.sin(th)*np.cos(ph)`
`y = R*np.sin(th)*np.sin(ph)`
`z = R*np.cos(th)`
`x1 = R*np.sin(th)*np.cos(ph)`
`y1 = R*np.sin(th)*np.sin(ph)`
`z1 = R*np.cos(th)`
`ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')`
`ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')`
`ax.plot_surface(x1+2, y1+2, z1+2, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')`
`ax.set_title('sphere')`

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: You're using `math.sin` and `math.cos`, which expect numbers but you're giving them arrays (`th` and `ph`). Use `numpy.sin` and `numpy.cos`

Problem 2: I think you have  misunderstood how [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) work. In spherical coordinates, we have `R`, `theta`, and `phi` where `R` is the _distance of the point from the origin.
When you use `R = 1`, you get points on a sphere of radius 1. To get points *inside* the sphere, you have to use a smaller radius than 1. For example, if you want to create 10 concentric spheres inside your sphere of radius 1, define an `rvec` using `linspace` and add it to the `meshgrid` like so:

```
N = 50
thetavec = np.linspace(0,pi,N)
phivec = np.linspace(0,2*pi,2*N)
rvec = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
[th, ph, R] = np.meshgrid(thetavec,phivec, rvec)

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten(), '.')
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want concentric circles but just want random points inside the sphere, you can use random numbers using `numpy.random.rand`. Unlike `numpy.ones`, `numpy.random.rand` requires the shape of the array as separate arguments instead of a single tuple, so we unpack the `th.shape` tuple using `*th.shape`.

```
N = 50
max_rad = 1
thetavec = np.linspace(0,pi,N)
phivec = np.linspace(0,2*pi,2*N)
[th, ph] = np.meshgrid(thetavec,phivec)
R = np.random.rand(*th.shape) * max_rad

x = R*np.sin(th)*np.cos(ph)
y = R*np.sin(th)*np.sin(ph)
z = R*np.cos(th)

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten(), '*')
```

[image]